# global object $this->configuration in symfony4

Tags: symfony

First of all, please, my intention is not to use any injections on the constructor.

I can't use `getParameter` either because the configuration comes from the database.

I explain myself:

I created a table of configuration in the database that is common for the whole application and I need to get the data in every controller and in every listener. So what I'm looking for is something global like symfony with doctrine.

`$this->getDoctrine`, but I want `$this->myconfiguration`

Is it possible to do this? or is there any better option?

Thanks

Comment: How about creating a service? `$this->getDoctrine` is just a wrapper for `$this->get('doctrine')` (plus some additional checks) in the `Controller` class (that you probably extend). You can just write your own (abstract) Controller that extends the original one and have all your usual Controllers extend that one aswell.

Comment: thanks @ccKep was exactly what I was looking for, and besides I didn't know about the wrapper, look I created my own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the answer of @ccKep, I can answer my question, I hope it will help someone.

First we register the service in `services.yml`

```
services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        public: false       # Allows optimizing the container by removing unused services; this also means
                            # fetching services directly from the container via $container->get() won't work.
                            # The best practice is to be explicit about your dependencies anyway.
    app.configuration:
        class: App\Service\Configuration
        arguments: 
            - "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
            - "@service_container"
```

Then we create the service inside the `src/service/Configuration.php`

I have also added the file cache system, to reduce the requests a little, since these requests will be done in the whole application.

```
<?php
namespace App\Service;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\Cache\Simple\FilesystemCache;

class Configuration
{  
   private $em;
   private $container;

   public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager,ContainerInterface $container) {

      $this->container     = $container;
      $this->em            = $entityManager;
   }

   public function byID($id){

        $cache = new FilesystemCache();

        if (!$cache->has('configuration.id'.$id)) {

            $configuration = $this->em->getRepository('App:Configuration')->find($id); 

            if (!$configuration) {
                throw new \Exception('Ninguna Configuración encontrado con el ID ' . $id);
            }

            $cache->set('configuration.id'.$id, $configuration,3600);
        }

        $configuration=$cache->get('configuration.id'.$id);

        dump($configuration);

        die();
   }

}
```

Now all that needs to be done is to request the service on any controller

```
$configuration = $this->get("configuration")->byID(1);
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out, don't forget to accept your answer! Regarding the cache, beware the warning on the [FileSystem Cache Adapter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/cache/adapters/filesystem_adapter.html) page in the docs: *The overhead of filesystem IO often makes this adapter one of the slower choices. If throughput is paramount, the in-memory adapters (Apcu, Memcached, and Redis) or the database adapters (Doctrine and PDO) are recommended.* - in your case, you might just want to query the repository always and just get rid of the caching.

Comment: You could use a local variable in case you call that method multiple times during one request though. Beware to reset it though once you write to that (could do that automatically using a doctrine event listener or manually if it doesn't happen in that many places).